# Cannot update mysql column from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a column of a database's table using this

```
$url = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $usrpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$url) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT adv_val FROM current_advert";

if($result = mysqli_query($url, $sql)){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $adv_val = $row['adv_val'];        
        }
} 
echo "current advert is:" . $adv_val;

// Attempt select query execution

$sql = "SELECT advert_text FROM advertisements WHERE advert_id = $adv_val";

if($result = mysqli_query($url, $sql)){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $advert = $row['advert_text'];        
        }
}
echo "<br>current advert text is:" . $advert;


if ($adv_val == 1 OR $adv_val == 2 OR $adv_val == 3) {
    $adv_val = $adv_val + 1;
} else {
    $adv_val = 1;
}

$sql = "UPDATE current_advert SET adv_val='$adv_val'";
// Close connection
echo "<br>next advert id is:" . $adv_val;
mysqli_close($url);
```

The connection to the database is ok since i'm able to read data from it in the beginning of my script. This is killing me!

Comment: @AmrAly `where` condition is not required if you want to upadte all rows

Comment: I did this earlier, did not change anything. Retrieving data without using the condition is working well. Why wouldn't it be the case with update as well?

Comment: can you post bit more of code on how you are updating?

Comment: Post more code.

Comment: @bansi You are right.

Comment: you are missing `mysqli_query($url, $sql);`

Comment: May be you forget to execute update query!!

Comment: Oh, really? Why am I so retarded -_-

Comment: This is nice, @bansi has pointed out the fault and now people post same logic as an answer to gain reputation :)

Comment: I fixed it thanks @Bansi

Comment: @Learner let them :) I don't worry about the reputation.

Comment: @bansi - well said

Comment: @Learner I don't think the guy who posted the solution is trying to gain reputation. he also saw your mistake, like I also did from the first time I checked your code then I read the comments and saw u have a solution already. So best u delete the post so we can not have an unaswered questions

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile, dude, i didn't ask the question. And about catching mistake, I believe you but then why you didnt post your answer? because you saw that problem was already resolved in comments so no more need to have an answer. Same i expect from others. Why to add an answer when you see that problem is already resolved? because i noticed that answer got posted AFTER the fault has been located.

Comment: @Nox, yes you should remove the question as its solved already.

Comment: @Learner sorry man, thought this was your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $sql = "UPDATE current_advert SET adv_val='$adv_val'";
 mysqli_query($url, $sql);
```

you are missing the 2nd line.